# How do I fix this warning- Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>. below is my code

Tags: javascript

```
function Download() {
    return (
        <div className="download">
            <div className="dow-container">
                <div className="download-btn">
                    <p className="download-name">Click To Download</p>
                    <div className="btns">
                        <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adis.cows" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                            <div className="google">
                                <img src={playstore} alt="playstore" />
                                <div className="btn-name">
                                    <p className="btn-name-get">GET IT ON</p>
                                    <a className="btn-name-google" href="#download">Google play</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <a href="/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                            <div className="apple">
                                <img src={apple} alt="apple" />
                                <div className="btn-name">
                                    <p className="btn-name-on">Download on the</p>
                                    <a className="btn-name-apple" href="#download">Apple Store</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="mobile-img">
                    <img src={screenshot} alt="img" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: How you can fix this? By creating valid markup. It is not valid to put a Link inside of a Link. Nor does it make sense. Which url do you want to open, when you basically click at both links at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, you cannot place an `<a>` tag inside another `<a>` tag which you are doing (as you are storing some `<div>`, `<p>` and also `<a>` tags inside a parent `<a>`).
So if you click the nested link (i.e, `<a>` tag inside another `<a>` tag), it will get confused whether to take you to the location of parent `<a>` or nested `<a>`. That is why, you cannot place an `<a>` tag inside another `<a>` tag.